# On post-back i didn't want to change the visuals of form?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a form with two div elements one is **Display:none** by default and the other one is showing when the page is open first time.I have toggle checkbox when i user press the checkbox then the hidden element shows and the user put their values in that input and submit the form.but what if user didn't put the data in input then the model validation works and form post-back and the first div hide again.I want that on post-back this div didn't hide.
Thanks

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateNewTotalizerTag", "TotalizerTags", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <!-- general form elements disabled -->
                <div class="card card-warning">
                    <div class="card-header" style="background-color:#343a40">
                        <h3 class="card-title" style="color:white">Create Totalizer Tag</h3>
                    </div>
                    <!-- This form is to create Raw tag totalizer onPrem or onCloud -->
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form role="form">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="custom-control custom-switch">

                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Is_Cloud_Totalizer, new { @class = "custom-control-input", id = "Is_Cloud_Totalizer" })
                                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="Is_Cloud_Totalizer">Is Cloud Totalizer?</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- On Cloud Inputs starts here -->
                            <div  id="oncloud_totalizer">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6" id="tag_name" style="display:none">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Enter Tag Name</label>
                                            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.R_Tag_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.R_Tag_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Select Raw Tag</label>
                                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Real_Tag_Id, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.RawTaglist, "Select Raw Tag", new { @class = "form-control", id = "Raw_Tag_List" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Real_Tag_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <center><button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Totalizer</button></center>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-body -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.card -->
                <!-- general form elements disabled -->
                <!-- /.card -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Initialize select2
        $("#Raw_Tag_List").select2();


        $("#Is_Cloud_Totalizer").change(function (e) {
            if (this.checked) {
                $("#tag_name").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#tag_name").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does the checkbox value get submitted to the server? If so you can use razor code to look at its value in your model, and decide whether to set the display:none (and also control the initial state of the checkbox).

Comment: yes its saving in ther server can you please guide how I can do this

Comment: well I've already suggested the way, in my first comment. Was there something specific in what I said that you didn't understand? I assume you know that you can use Razor code to change the HTML.